# Python Google Web app, Send file to Dropbox

Tags: python, google-app-engine, dropbox-api

I am developing a Google web app using their Google app engine to parse some data from various incoming sources and save it all to one place. My ultimate goal is to save the file on a Dropbox, but the Google app hosting service dose't allow me to save files on the disk. Is there a way to send raw data to a Dropbox app and have that app save it as a file?

Comment: Have you tried the blobstore files API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write to a file in Google's AppEngine by using either BlobStore (https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/overview#Writing_Files_to_the_Blobstore) or Google Cloud Storage (https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/googlestorage/overview)

To write to a file using the dropbox api, have a look here: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/api#files-POST

You'll have to setup an authenticated request, but this will write the contents of your POST body into a file into the authenticated user's Dropbox.

I think for the Blobstore, Google Cloud Storage, and DropBox you cannot append to existing files, so if you need to do this you need to either create a new file for each time you want to write data and combine files at a later point or read in the previous files data and prepend it to the new data before writing the new data.